# Find the total edges in a Graph (C)

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

i have these functions :

**Create Graph**

```
 struct Graph* createGraph(int V) { 
 struct Graph* graph = 
 (struct Graph*) malloc(sizeof(struct Graph)); 
 graph->V = V; 
 graph->array = 
(struct AdjList*) malloc(V * sizeof(struct AdjList)); 
int i; 
for (i = 0; i < V; ++i) 
    graph->array[i].head = NULL; 
return graph; }
```

**Add edge**

```
void addEdge(struct Graph* graph, int src, int dest){ 
struct AdjListNode* newNode = newAdjListNode(dest); 
newNode->next = graph->array[src].head; 
graph->array[src].head = newNode; 
newNode = newAdjListNode(src); 
newNode->next = graph->array[dest].head; 
graph->array[dest].head = newNode;}
```

**Print Graph**

```
void printGraph(struct Graph* graph){ 
int v; 
for (v = 0; v < graph->V; ++v) 
{ 
    struct AdjListNode* pCrawl = graph->array[v].head; 
    printf("\n Adjacency list of vertex %d head -> ", v); 
    while (pCrawl) 
    { 
        printf("[%d] ", pCrawl->dest); 
        pCrawl = pCrawl->next; 
    } 
    printf("\n"); } }
```

With these functions i have the following output which is correct:

```
 Adjacency list of vertex 0 head -> [4] [1]  
 Adjacency list of vertex 1 head -> [4] [3] [2] [0]
 Adjacency list of vertex 2 head -> [3] [1]
 Adjacency list of vertex 3 head -> [4] [2] [1]
 Adjacency list of vertex 4 head -> [3] [1] [0]
```

I want to make a fuction in which i can count the total edges in this graph.

[Here you can see the total edges are 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXADJ.png)

I made this code :

```
int counttotalEdges(struct Graph* graph){
 int v,sum;
 sum = 0;
    for (v = 0; v < graph->V; ++v) 
    { 
       struct AdjListNode* pCrawl = graph->array[v].head; 
        while (pCrawl) 
    {  
        sum = sum + 1;
        pCrawl = pCrawl->next; 
    } 
}
return sum; }
```

and the output is :

```
The total Edges in graph are : 14
```

which is wrong because it counts some edges more than one time.

**The correct output should be 7**

How can i fix it?

Comment: Divide the result by two if it's a directed graph?

Comment: @ggorlen Yes i can divide it by 2 but this will work in every graph? It is an undirected graph

Comment: Test it on a self-edge and take that into consideration, but otherwise as long as every edge links two nodes, it should work.

Comment: @ggorlen Yeah ok i am gonna test it to see if it works in every graph